# Sitecore Layout Parameters Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Currently getting an InvalidOperationException on loading 2 sublayout parameters on a rendering to change their values. They are named "Title" and "Text" respectively and both are single-line text boxes.  I am able to change the parameters on the same item but different rendering. The other rendering contains a general link and an image.

Anyone run into this and able to shed a bit of light?

```
[InvalidOperationException: field]
Sitecore.Data.FieldDescriptor..ctor(Item item, String fieldName) +221
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.RenderingParameters.GetAdditionalParameters(List`1 fieldDescriptors, Item standardValues, Dictionary`2 additionalParameters) +430
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.RenderingParameters.GetFields(RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition, Dictionary`2 parameters) +902
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.RenderingParameters.Show() +266
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Dialogs.LayoutDetails.LayoutDetailsForm.EditRenderingPipeline(ClientPipelineArgs args) +356
```

Comment: What do you mean "loading 2 sublayout parameters on a rendering to change their values"? Programatically from your own code, or default Sitecore interface?

Comment: @jammykam Not sure if it was because it was Monday or not, but this was in the default Sitecore interface that I'm seeing the error.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that error didn't make sense with what you were saying. BTW, this is useful for getting access to the sublayout parameters: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sub_Layout_Parameter_Helper.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown by the code:

```
Field field = item.Fields[fieldName];
Assert.IsNotNull(field, "field");
```

It looks like either you haven't set the field name or you have a typo in a name field or the item does not have the field with a name you're passing as a parameter.

Comment: fieldName is passed in though, not something it is looking for. `new FieldDescriptor(standardValues, "Additional Parameters")` is what is called in `GetAdditionalParameters`.